# Typing while animation UITextView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, uitextview, typing

I'm trying to have a variable-height UITextView which changes size to accomodate its contents, but when the frame changes in the size-change animation, one or two keystrokes aren't captured in the UITextView. The animation duration is 0.1s, and typically it only misses one letter when you're typing fairly fast. It is, however, very consistent in missing letters when the animation happens. The following animation block occurs within the textViewDidChange: delegate message:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{

    [textView setFrame:CGRectMake(...)];

}];
```

I've Googled and searched on SO, but so far nothing has come up. Has anyone else encountered this?

Comment: Why don't you try how it looks without an animation? It might not look bad, and as a user, I'd trade the animation for not missing keystrokes anytime.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default UIView animations disable user interaction for animated view, so possibly (sorry cannot test it now) explicitly enabling user interaction will solve your problem:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 
        delay:0.0
        options: UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
        animations:^{    
            [textView setFrame:CGRectMake(...)];
        }    
        completion:^(void){}];
```

Comment: Thanks, Vladimir, for the incredibly prompt response. That worked beautifully.