# How to detect touches on UIImageView while it's animating

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

I have an UIImageview which moves from a position to another. When I try to tap on the image during the animation touch event delegate method is not called. But when I tap on image after the completion of the animation, the delegate method executes. How can I detect the touch event on the uiimageview while it is changing its position.

my code:

```
vwb2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(240, 500, 50, 50)];
[self.view addSubview:vwb2];
ballon2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"b2.png"]];
ballon2.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;
ballon2.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50);
[vwb2 addSubview:ballon2];
[ballon2 release];
```

**Edit:**

My code for animation:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                 animations:^{ 
                     vwb1.center = CGPointMake(260, 40);
                 } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){

                     [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5
                                      animations:^{ 
                                          vwb2.center = CGPointMake(260, 100);
                                      } 
                                      completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                          [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                                                           animations:^{ 
                                                               vwb3.center = CGPointMake(260, 160);
                                                           } 
                                                           completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                                               [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                                                                                animations:^{ 
                                                                                    vwb4.center = CGPointMake(260, 220);
                                                                                } 
                                                                                completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                                                                    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{ 
                                                                                        vwb5.center = CGPointMake(260, 280);
                                                                                    } ];
                                                                                }];
                                                           }];

                                      }
                      ];

                 }];
```

Thanks
Pankaj

Comment: How do you animate your image?

Comment: Check this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852020/typing-while-animation-uitextview/6852092#6852092, it is not exactly the same, but you probably have similar problem and that solution will do the trick for you

Comment: I upvoted @Vladimir's answer in his link. Its great.

Comment: @vladimir hi I have updated my code here which is similar to what you have mentioned in link given by you. But my question I am not able to get touch event when my image is changing its position. I am getting the touch once animation is over but during animation

Comment: @Pankaj, have you tried solution from the link I posted?

Comment: hi Vladimir, I tried adding UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction to my code using your answer but I am getting warning because of UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction keyword. System is not able to recognise it as a keyword

Comment: @pankaj, where do you put UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction?

Comment: @Vladimir, it is working perfect now, I was using it wrong way earlier. I checked it thoroughly and it worked. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have posted correct solution as edit to my original question

Answer (score 0):

You can get position...

```
-(CGRect) getPos
{
    CGRect pos = 0;
    CALayer *layer = yourAnimationView.layer.presentationLayer;
    if(layer)
        pos = layer.frame;

    return pos;
}
```

And check  CGRectContainsPoint([self getPos],touchPoint) in touchesEnded method
([My old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895674/how-to-detect-touches-on-uiimageview-while-its-animating/6895816#6895816))

Comment: but my problem is I am not able to get the touch event on image while it is still changing its position.

Answer (score 0):

In my project, I did not detect any touch event of UIImageView.
I detected touch event of parent view and used touch point and UIImageView's rect to detect the UIImageView was touched.
Maybe you can try it.

```
- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint pt = [touch locationInView:self];
    bool inX = NO;
    bool inY = NO;
    if(pt.x >= myImgView.frame.origin.x && pt.x <= myImgView.frame.origin.x + myImgView.frame.size.width)
        inX = YES;
    if(pt.y >= myImgView.frame.origin.y && pt.y <= myImgView.frame.origin.y + myImgView.frame.size.height)
        inY = YES;
    if(inX && inY)
        NSLog(@"myImgView is touched");
}
```

Comment: touchesEnded delegate method is not being called during animation. It is only executed when I touch an image once it has stopped moving.