# UITouch Event on Animated UIImagevIew

Tags: image, animation, random, uitouch

I am using the Snowfall sample code which drops UImages from the top of the screen. I want to detect a Touch on the UIImageview and update a label. If i create a single UIImageView in IBOutlet and connect it to the touch event the label is updated correctly. But when I try to apply it to the falling UIImageView it does not work. Here is what I have so far:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];

     score = 0;
     self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.5 green:0.5 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0];
     flakeImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"flake.png"];

     [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(0.5) target:self selector:@selector(onTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)onTimer
{

    flakeView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:flakeImage];
    flakeView.opaque = YES;
    flakeView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    flakeView.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;

     int startX = round(random() % 320);
     int endX = round(random() % 320);

     double scale = 1 / round(random() % 100) + 1.0;
     double speed = 1 / round(random() % 100) + 1.0;

     flakeView.frame = CGRectMake(startX, -100.0, 25.0 * scale, 25.0 * scale);

     [self.view addSubview:flakeView];
     [self.view bringSubviewToFront:flakeView];

     [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:flakeView];
     [UIView setAnimationDuration:5 * speed];

     flakeView.frame = CGRectMake(endX, 500.0, 25.0 * scale, 25.0 * scale);

     [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(onAnimationComplete:finished:context:)];
     [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
     [UIView commitAnimations];     
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    if ([touch view] == flakeView)
    {
        NSLog(@"tag %@",touch);
        score = score + 1;
        lbl1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", score];        
    }
}
```

Comment: here is the solution of your problem..

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852020/typing-while-animation-uitextview/6852092#6852092

Answer (score 1):

Animations typically disable touch handling so you have to use:

```
 animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion
```

to set the options to receive touches.

http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH6-SW1

IIRC the option you want is:  UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction   Look for UIViewAnimationOptions in the above doc for the full list.

Comment: [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 delay:0.0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:flakeView];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:5 * speed];
        flakeView.frame = CGRectMake(endX, 500.0, 25.0 * scale, 25.0 * scale);
        [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(onAnimationComplete:finished:context:)];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        [UIView commitAnimations];} completion:nil];

Comment: I have tried this before and put this in after I added the flakeView as a subview. But still no success.

Comment: The beginAnimations in the animations block is likely the problem.  Every animation you want to allow interaction has to have UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction specified.